# How to install oauth module in xampp in ubuntu

Tags: php, oauth, xampp

I have installed xampp on ubuntu 14.04 LTS, php version is 5.5.6. I am new to this and read so many articles but failed to install oauth module in proper directory. Please help me on this issue. And tell me how to install oauth module in xampp (localhost/opt/lampp) directory, so that I can consume magento rest services.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi , to visit [this URL](http://askubuntu.com/), it could be more info to aid you.

Comment: @Ajinkya were you able to install it?